# Decomposition $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\cong G_1 \times G_2$ for $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I want to prove that if $p$ is a prime and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\cong G_1 \times G_2$, then either $G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ or $G_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$

I have tried to approach this problem with the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, but I cannot get anywhere. Thank you for any help, advice, or solution!

Comment: Can you please show how exactly you tried to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Bbb Z_{p^n}\simeq G_1\times G_2$ both $G_1$ and $G_2$ must be groups with a number of elements given by a power of $p$ (such groups are called $p$-groups).

Any non-trivial $p$-group needs to contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p$, so if neither $G_1$ nor $G_2$ is trivial, the product $G=G_1\times G_2$ contains (at least) $p^2$ elements of order $p$. But this is false for $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ which contains exactly $p$ elements of order $p$.

This proves that one of the $G_i$ is trivial.

About the existence of elements of exact order $p$ in $p$-groups, one can use Cauchy's theorem which says just that for any finite group of order divisible by $p$. But in case of abelian groups (which is the situation we are in) the fact follows readily from the structure theorem of abelian groups.

More generally, a product of two finite groups is cyclic if and only if the two factors are cyclic of coprime orders.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am seeing it, but I am having a hard time with one part. If both $G_1$ and $G_2$ contain subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, why must it be that $G_1 \times G_2$ contains at least $p^2$ elements of order $p$?

Comment: If $a\in G_1$ has order $p$ and $b\in G_2$ has order $p$, then $(a,b)$ has order $p$ in $G_1\times G_2$.

Comment: @ajotatxe OK, I think I understand now. There must be $p$ such elements $a$ in $G_1$ and $p$ such elements $b$ in $G_2$. These are the generators of the subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Is that correct? I apologize, I have not thought about group theory for a very long time.

Comment: @user276953: If $\Bbb Z_p<G_1$ and $\Bbb Z_p<G_2$ then $(\Bbb Z_p)^2<G_1\times G_2$